# Encrypting connection string - allowing other machines to decrypt

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms, connection-string, aspnet-regiis.exe

I'm trying to develop a C# Winform application, which connects to SQL database.

My configuration file looks as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
<configSections>
</configSections>
<connectionStrings>
<add name="myConnNameString"
providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"
connectionString="Data Source=myServerName;Initial 
Catalog=myDefDatabase;User=myUser;Password=myPassword;Application Name=myAppName" />
</connectionStrings>
<startup>
<supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2" />
</startup>
</configuration>
```

I was able to succesfully encrypt this file via:

```
aspnet_regiis.exe -pef "connectionStrings" path_to_config_file
```

But once I did that I can't run my application normally anymore.
Now I can do this only by running it as an Administrator

```
Cannot decrypt with provider RsaProtectedConfigurationProvider.
Cannot open key container RSA
```

Now as far as I understand this:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/msp-n-p/ff650304(v=pandp.10)

I have created a RSA with Machine Level Container so only a machine which encrypted a file can
decrypt it, a no other machines can do it.

How can I let other machines decrypt this file aswell?
My application is stored in a single directory on a remote network drive, to which everyone has access to.
The application is run on their computers via shortcut.

Thank you in advance!

EDIT: 
It is also worth to mention that, not every person in our company has a local admininistator permission.

Comment: Not a direct answer, but another way to do this would be to *not* store credentials for a single username / password in the config, but rather specify A/D authentication ('Trusted_Connection=True;'), and then set permissions in the database for A/D users / groups to access.

Comment: We did consider that posssibility, but we had some serious problems with access to objects on the databases, so we decided to create a single sql user with superior permissions.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/connection-strings-and-configuration-files#encrypting-configuration-file-sections-using-protected-configuration

Answer (score 0):

Ok so this what I've accomplished so far:

Created exportable RSA machine-level key container

```
aspnet_regiis -pc "MyKeys" -exp
```

Now I'm granting read access to that conatiner to a NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE account(whatever it is)

```
aspnet_regiis -pa "MyKeys" "NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE"
```

Then I encrypted my configuration file with my custom provider

```
aspnet_regiis -pef "connectionStrings" "path_to_config_file" - 
prov "myCustomProvider"
```

The configuration file looks a follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
<configProtectedData>
<providers>
  <add name="myCustomProvider"
       type="System.Configuration.RsaProtectedConfigurationProvider, 
                System.Configuration, Version=2.0.0.0,
                Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a,
                processorArchitecture=MSIL"
                keyContainerName="MyKeys"
                useMachineContainer="true" />
</providers>
</configProtectedData>
<configSections>
</configSections>
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="myConnectionString"
    providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"
    connectionString="Data Source=myServerName;Initial 
    Catalog=myDefDatabase;User=myUser;Password=myPassword;Application 
    Name=myAppName" />
</connectionStrings>
<startup>
<supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2" />
</startup>
</configuration>
```

Then I export my RSA key container to a file:

```
-px "MyKeys" "C:\Users\name.surname\Desktop\test\test.xml" -pri
```

And where should I import this xml file now?
Does every user of my program has to exec this line?

```
aspnet_regiis -pi "MyKeys" test.xml
```

Now when I try to run my Winform program (even on the machine where the encryption was performed) I'm getting following error message:

> Cannot decrypt using a provider myCustomProvider.
>   Provider error message.
>   An error occurred while decoding OAEP completion

Any help will be greatly apprecieate.